# Redis self-healing cluster or alternative in cloud, Kubernetes or Swarm?

Tags: redis, kubernetes, consul

Is it possible to deploy a self-healing and scaling Redis-like key-value store that I can run in Kubernetes (or Swarm or any other automated cloud env)?

The challenges I found with Redis:

1. You need to create a cluster manually with `redis-trib`
2. New nodes need to be added to the cluster explicitly
3. Nodes need to be removed explicitly
4. Nodes do not replicate data in their shards peer to peer, but rather use a master-slave model

The above means that the following scenarios all will fail. I have a simple 3-master and 3-slave cluster. "Master A" fails, leading Kubernetes to start a new "Master A" in <1 second:

- new "Master A" has no knowledge of the cluster and will not join
- "Slave A", which had copies of the data, now syncs from the new "Master A", and loses all data, defeating the purpose of slave replica
- In completely new startup, "Master A" might start before "Master B", is initialized (assuming I even can automate the cluster init), before "Master B" is ready, and thus "Master B" never really joins the cluster

Questions:

1. Is there a way to automate Redis cluster init and sync in a non-predictable, non-persistent storage without *any* human interaction?
2. If not, is there an alternative that is a clean, in-memory key-value store (persistence is less important to me), that is self-healing and works peer-to-peer?

Consul/etcd/zookeeper all work 100% peer-to-peer and self-heal (which is great), but their performance (supposedly) is far below Redis in-memory KV. They aren't built, e.g. for looking up a session with each Web API request. This is partially due to non-sharding (100% copies), partially due to disk writes.

Kafka's model (although a message queue, not a KV store) works well too (but depends on zk underneath): partitions and replicas, but essentially self-healing. I talk to one broker, it tells me where my topic ("shard") lives, I get it.

Is there any way to get that full autonomy using Redis so I can deploy in kube/swarm/cloud, or an alternative that provides similar performance with the autonomous model?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Kubernetes Redis Example which work with Redis Sentinel. In case the master fails, sentinel promotes a slave to the new master. The Replication Controller boots a new Slave Pod. Your application connects to sentinel and from that service you will get the ip of the new master.

Redis Sentinel https://redis.io/topics/sentinel

Kubernetes Example https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/storage/redis

Comment: I came across this before, but let it go for several reasons. First, I didn't realize that sentinel handles not only cluster creation/joining/replacement. So I don't need any `redis-trib` when using sentinel? Second, what happens with masters-slaves? Wouldn't sentinel try to promote a slave to a master while kube is replacing the master, thus creating a conflict, and possibly wiping out data? The example doesn't use slaves, would it even work with sentinel+kube? Last, I would have assumed statefulset over deployment (or RC)?

Comment: At first you create a master pod. This is the only one which start as master. 
The redis-controller starts all redis pods as slaves. You see that in the start file. If no options are provided redis starts as a slave After all of these pods are running, you can delete the master pod and a random slave pod will promote to new master. The recreated pod from the controller will start as a new slave.
You don't need redis-trib. But your application needs to handle the requests with sentinel.

Comment: I would prefer to use deployment instead of statefulset. If the master crashs, kubernetes will delete the pod and recreate the new slave. In this time (1 minute) it has promote another slave to master.

Comment: Be aware that Redis Sentinel has just a subset of the capabilities compared to Redis Cluster. Automating a Redis Sentinel deployment in k8s should be easy, there is a Helm chart just for that (`redis-ha`).

Comment: take care, the bitnami/redis sentinel integration is really fragile and not stable. didnt even run smoothly in the first production tests and never recovered successfully.